# Parsing XML Data with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

actually I am working on a small project and need to parse public available XML data. My goal is to write the data to an mysql database for further processing.

XML Data Link: http://offenedaten.frankfurt.de/dataset/912fe0ab-8976-4837-b591-57dbf163d6e5/resource/48378186-5732-41f3-9823-9d1938f2695e/download/parkdatendyn.xml

XML structure (example):

```
<parkingAreaStatus>
      <parkingAreaOccupancy>0.2533602</parkingAreaOccupancy>
      <parkingAreaOccupancyTrend>stable</parkingAreaOccupancyTrend>
      <parkingAreaReference targetClass="ParkingArea" id="2[Zeil]" 
       version="1.0"/>
      <parkingAreaStatusTime>2018-02-
       04T01:30:00.000+01:00</parkingAreaStatusTime  
      </parkingAreaStatus>

<parkingAreaStatus>
      <parkingAreaOccupancy>0.34625</parkingAreaOccupancy>
      <parkingAreaOccupancyTrend>stable</parkingAreaOccupancyTrend>
      <parkingAreaReference targetClass="ParkingArea" id="5[Dom / Römer]" 
       version="1.0"/>
      </parkingAreaStatus>
```

Using the code

```
import csv
import pymysql
import urllib.request

url = "http://offenedaten.frankfurt.de/dataset/912fe0ab-8976-4837-b591-57dbf163d6e5/resource/48378186-5732-41f3-9823-9d1938f2695e/download/parkdatendyn.xml"

from lxml.objectify import parse
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen
locations_root = parse(urlopen(url)).getroot()


locations = list(locations_root.payloadPublication.genericPublicationExtension.parkingFacilityTableStatusPublication.parkingAreaStatus.parkingAreaReference)

print(*locations)
```

I expected to get a list of all "parkingAreaReference" entries within the XML document. Unfortunately the list is empty.

Playing arround with some code I got the sentiment that only the first  block is parsed, I was able to fill the list with the value of "parkingAreaOccupancy" of the "parkingAreaReference" id="2[Zeil]" block by using the code

```
locations = list(locations_root.payloadPublication.genericPublicationExtension.parkingFacilityTableStatusPublication.parkingAreaStatus.parkingAreaOccupancy)

 print(*locations)
```

-> 0.2533602

which is not the expected outcome

-> 0.2533602
-> 0.34625

MY question is:

What is the best way to get a matrix i can further work with of all  blocks incl. the corresponding values stated in the XML document?

Example output:

```
A = [[ID:2[Zeil],0.2533602,stable,2018-02-
   04T01:30:00.000+01:00],[id="5[Dom / Römer],0.34625,stable,2018-02-
   04T01:30:00.000+01:00]]
```

or in general

```
A = [parkingAreaOccupancy,parkingAreaOccupancyTrend,parkingAreaStatusTime,....],[parkingAreaOccupancy,parkingAreaOccupancyTrend,parkingAreaStatusTime,.....]
```

After hours of research I hope for some tips from your site

Thank you in advance,

TR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `etree` directly and find interesting elements using XPath<sup>1</sup> query. One important thing to note is, that your XML has default namespace declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
```

By definition, element where default namespace is declared and all descendant elements without prefix are belong to this default namespace (unless another default namespace found in one of the descendant elements, which is not the case with your XML). This is why we define a prefix `d`, which references default namespace URI, in the following code, and we use that prefix to find every elements we need to get information from :

```
root = etree.parse(urlopen(url)).getroot()
ns = { 'd': 'http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0' }
parking_area = root.xpath('//d:parkingAreaStatus', namespaces=ns)
for pa in parking_area:
    area_ref = pa.find('d:parkingAreaReference', ns)
    occupancy = pa.find('d:parkingAreaOccupancy', ns)
    trend = pa.find('d:parkingAreaOccupancyTrend', ns)
    status_time = pa.find('d:parkingAreaStatusTime', ns)
    print area_ref.get('id'), occupancy.text, trend.text, status_time.text
```

Below is the output of the demo code above. Instead of `print`, you can store these information in whatever data structure you like :

```
2[Zeil] 0.22177419 stable 2018-02-04T05:16:00.000+01:00
5[Dom / Römer] 0.28625 stable 2018-02-04T05:16:00.000+01:00
1[Anlagenring] 0.257889 stable 2018-02-04T05:16:00.000+01:00
3[Mainzer Landstraße] 0.20594966 stable 2018-02-04T05:16:00.000+01:00
4[Bahnhofsviertel] 0.31513646 stable 2018-02-04T05:16:00.000+01:00
```

1) some references on XPath :

- [XPath 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/): The most trustworthy reference on XPath 1.0
- [XPath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp): Gentler introduction to basic XPath expressions

Comment: Thank you har07 - for the solution and the back ground Infos. People like you make stack overflow to what it is. Happy weekend